# Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run emulator for a project. IOS works with no problem. But when i try to use android emulator i keep getting this warning

Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugRFile'.

Even if i try to create new project with no navigation or gesture handler i get this warning.

What is the reason of this problem ?

Comment: show full error log

Answer (score -1):

It is probably due to these lines in `gradle.properties`. Just remove them

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: did you try to rebuild?